# How to filter duplicate rows and filter rows based on a single column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select co.id, udf.string_val, udf.id 

from customer_order co left join user_def_fields as udf on co.id = udf.document_id

where status = 'h' and order_date between '1/1/2016' and '12/31/2016' 

and co.id <> (select document_id from user_def_fields 

where (string_val = 'questions' or string_val = 'credit card' or string_val = 'credit hold' 
or string_val = 'design'))

co.id | String_val | udf.id
------|------------|--------
9798  | QUESTIONS  |UDF-000054 
9798  | RUSH ORDER |UDF-000047
9798  | RUSH ORDER |UDF-000024
9799  | RUSH ORDER |UDF-000047
9799  | RUSH ORDER |UDF-000024
9799  | DESIGN     |UDF-000054
9801  | RUSH ORDER |UDF-000047
9801  | RUSH ORDER |UDF-000024
9802  | NULL       |NULL
9803  | RUSH ORDER |UDF-000047
9803  | RUSH ORDER |UDF-000024
9803  | CHECKED    |UDF-000054
```

Here is a sample of the query results without any filters. Co.id is the order number, the various string_vals are notes within there respective udf fields, udf.id is the field id, and document_id is the order number reference in the udf table. Customer service enters 'Rush Order' in two fields, which is why it shows up twice. Sometimes no notes are entered and the udf fields are null. I really just need the co.id results returned and to be unique. From the above data sample, I want my query to return

```
co.id 
------
9801
9802
9803
```

My current query gives me an error because it returns multiple results.

Comment: I didn't understand your output.Can you please explain why you excluded 9798,9789,9799

Comment: Does this work:select co.id, udf.string_val, udf.id 
from 
customer_order co 
left join 
user_def_fields udf 
on co.id = udf.document_id
where status = 'h' and order_date between '1/1/2016' and '12/31/2016' 
and co.id not in (select document_id from user_def_fields 
where (string_val = 'questions' or string_val = 'credit card' or string_val = 'credit hold' 
or string_val = 'design'))

Comment: The purpose of the report is to display orders that are on hold ('h'), but don't have 'Questions', 'credit card', 'credit hold', or 'Design' holds on them. '9801', '9802', and '9803' don't have any of these conditions. But I only want to return one row for them.

Comment: `AND co.id <> (SELECT ` should be `AND co.id NOT IN (SELECT ` if your query returns multiple results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to avoid using DISTINCT.

```
SELECT  co.id
FROM    customer_order co
WHERE   status = 'h'
        AND order_date BETWEEN '1/1/2016' AND '12/31/2016'
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                         FROM   user_def_fields udf
                         WHERE  udf.document_id = co.id
                                AND string_val IN ('questions','credit card','credit hold','design')  
        )
```

or you could use left join and check for null

```
SELECT  co.id
FROM    customer_order co
        LEFT JOIN user_def_fields udf ON udf.document_id = co.id 
            AND udf.string_val IN ('questions','credit card','credit hold','design') 
WHERE   co.status = 'h'
        AND order_date BETWEEN '1/1/2016' AND '12/31/2016'
        AND udf.document_id IS NULL
```

Comment: can you explain why the bottom query with the left join works? How does using the IN operator as a join condition filter the results?

Comment: it doesn't filter the results.. the filter is `AND udf.document_id IS NULL`  so when you left join to udf on `string_val in (list)` if it finds a match, you will get values from udf in your result, if there is no match, you will only get values from co in your result.. so by checking a value in udf to see if it's null, you can tell if there was a match or not.

Comment: here is an example.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fdf08/2   if you want the records that match the join condition you would add `where document_id is not null` or just use `inner join`  but if you want the records that did not match the join condition you would add `where document_id is null`.. this would have to be in the `WHERE` and not the `JOIN`

Comment: I understand now. That's a great example! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you want to use the "Distinct" keyword. Distinct will suppress rows from the result set that have exactly the same data as another row already in the set. The issue will be that if you want truly distinct `co.id` values, that's the only column you'll be able to return (much like in your desired results), because distinct will return all rows with a distinct combination of any fields in the select list, which could still give you duplicate `co.id` values if `string_val` or `udf.id` differ between results. Your query would look like:

```
select distinct co.id    
from customer_order co 
left join user_def_fields udf 
    on co.id = udf.document_id    
where status = 'h' and order_date between '1/1/2016' and '12/31/2016'     
and co.id not in (select document_id from user_def_fields
    where (string_val = 'questions' or string_val = 'credit card' 
        or string_val = 'credit hold' or string_val = 'design'))
```

Comment: changing <> to not in or not exists will help when subquery may return more than one value

Comment: I get zero results when running the above query.

Comment: the `status` field could be messing with you; is that a field on `customer_order` or `user_def_fields`?

Comment: Status is in customer_order. When I take it out completely, it still returns zero rows.

Comment: K. Since you no longer need the join to `user_defined_fields` to put UDF data in the select list, you might try removing it and just keeping the subquery.

Comment: I took out all the extra filters to try to get results and it still returns zero rows. It is now only select id from customer_order where co.id not in (subquery mentioned above). What am I doing wrong here? I get 5,417 results from running the subquery by itself as a select.

Comment: I discovered the issue. The customer_order table and User_Def_Field table are not related in the database. I had to add "And udf.document_id = co.id" to the subquery where clause. Then it returned about 50 unique rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) keyword:

```
select distinct co.id
from customer_order co left join user_def_fields as udf on co.id = udf.document_id
where status = 'h' and order_date between '1/1/2016' and '12/31/2016' 
and co.id <> (select document_id from user_def_fields 
where (string_val = 'questions' or string_val = 'credit card' or string_val = 'credit hold' or string_val = 'design'))
```